# what is best practice for automating site structure creation?

Tags: powershell, farm-solution

I'm working on creating a website in SharePoint. I need a way to automate what I have done until now. For example I have created a web application and two site collections and bla bla.

Now I have two ways : Write a Powershell script to do all these stuff for me, OR Develop a farm solution for my environment setup.

I don't know which way is the best. Any suggestion ?

Answer (score 3):

If you are simply creating web applications, site collections, etc., I would use a PowerShell script.  I would only create a custom solution if you are adding custom content, such as web parts, master pages, etc.

Answer (score -1):

I would use code any day in the week, but not create a solution, just a SharePoint Console application ([CKSDev](http://cksdev.codeplex.com) template). I am just more comfortable using a good development environment and object oriented approach.